# Python: Pandas to read specific html table using it's unique table Caption

Tags: python, html, pandas, html-table

I'm starting out on Python pandas and need some guide. Assume I have a html file that consists of multiple tables and each table is uniquely identified by each table's Caption i.e. Table number 135, etc.

If I wish to make use of the unique caption "**Table 246**" to identify and read that table, how can Python Pandas specifically read this table while ignoring the other tables? I need to read this **Table 246** using it's Caption because, the order of the table in this file is not fix, it is dynamic.

Have been searching the internet but didn't find any solution on using Table's caption to identify that table.

**My html file contents**

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
<p>
<table border=1>
<caption align=left>Table 135</caption>
<tr bgcolor="#d4d0c8" bordercolor=black>
<th bordercolor=black>User Name</th>
<th bordercolor=black>Mobile Number</th>
</tr>
<tr bordercolor=black>
<td bordercolor=black bgcolor=white>John</td>
<td bordercolor=black bgcolor=white>1234567890</td>
</tr>
</table>
</p>
<p>
<table border=1>
<caption align=left>Table 246</caption>
<tr bgcolor="#d4d0c8" bordercolor=black>
<th bordercolor=black>Salary</th>
<th bordercolor=black>Experience</th>
</tr>
<tr bordercolor=black>
<td bordercolor=black bgcolor=white>$5000</td>
<td bordercolor=black bgcolor=white>10</td>
</tr>
</table>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you checked the docs for reading the html table in pandas ? since you are new to this forum(i am guessing) i suggest first look for the previous answers..or for similar questions..you will learn more this way...or wait for someone to answer this for you..Thanks for understanding !

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following code to extract the html table:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_html("test.html", match='Table 246')
df[0]
```

Example Code:

https://github.com/biranchi2018/Misc/blob/master/1.Extracting%20HTML%20using%20Pandas.ipynb

Thanks